# Multi-level Hover Navigation Bar with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover, dropdown

So I'm looking at the code on w3schools.com and there are a few good examples and I'm trying to make heads or tails of it all. But they don't offer instructions on customizing the code for a third level of menus. Could someone break this code down for me so I can add multiple levels of menus at will?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>Title</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Also could someone explain to me here where and how this code tells the browser the overall width of the navbar. I tried someone else code on here and the nav bar was stuck at only 150px. When I changed the width values it got all buggy. So I know I'm just not understanding where this is determined in the code.

Update: Thanks to one of the answers I've figured out how to get the tertiary menu in and fumbled through getting the menu to pop out to the right. Now my issue is that it extends the dropdown menu under "Link 3" as though it were making room for the links below it. How would I remove this? Here's my current code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>Title</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%; /*red background color width*/
  text-align: start; /*text inside in red background color*/
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content-sub {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -46px;
  right: -300px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px; /*block width*/
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px; /*block width*/
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-sub:hover .dropdown-content-sub {
  display: block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
        
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
    <button class="dropbtn">Link 3 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Update 2 Final: So it seems my changing the position of the third tier from absolute to relative caused the undesired effect. Simply switching it back solved it and it all now works. :) I had to change the "top" position of the button after that but that was easy to figure out. Now I should be able to just place my links in each menu item and I'm good to go! :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Assuming [this](https://w3schoolsrus.github.io/howto/howto_css_dropdown.html) is the tutorial you followed, it seems pretty well explained to me. Can you be more precise in what part you are struggling with?

Comment: Yeah that's the one I'm using. I am assuming I need to add another block of CSS to the style and somehow use that in the body. I'm just not certain how this is all broken down in order to customize it. I'm addmittedly a bit green on css but if someone explained it to me I'm sure I could follow along.

Comment: I've updated the OP. Can you help me find the mistake causing the issue I mentioned in the update?

Comment: use `position: absolute`, not `position:relative`. [this article](https://medium.com/@leannezhang/difference-between-css-position-absolute-versus-relative-35f064384c6#:~:text=position%3A%20relative%20places%20an%20element,changing%20the%20layout%20around%20it.) explains the difference

Comment: @JannesCarpentier You're AWESOME! Thanks so much for the help! And the other person who deleted their answer. I'm not sure why they did that. But they totally helped me too. I should be able to take it from here. I'm not saying I understand it all but this solved my problem. Just wish I knew where in the code the size of the navbar and buttons are determined. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See updates in OP. Thanks to @JannesCarpentier and one other anonymous user for the help! Here's the code tweaked from w3schools.com to get 3-tiered hover navbar.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>Title</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%; /*red background color width*/
  text-align: start; /*text inside in red background color*/
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content-sub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85px;
  right: -300px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px; /*block width*/
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px; /*block width*/
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-sub:hover .dropdown-content-sub {
  display: block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
        
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
    <button class="dropbtn">Link 3 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>



</body>
</html>
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%; /*red background color width*/
  text-align: start; /*text inside in red background color*/
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content-sub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85px;
  right: -300px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px; /*block width*/
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px; /*block width*/
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-sub:hover .dropdown-content-sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
    <button class="dropbtn">Link 3
      <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```